# Spring Cloud Stream Binder with Glue Registry - AVRO

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, aws-glue, spring-cloud-stream

Any one able to integrates spring cloud stream binder with glue registry? I could only see documentation for confluent schema registry but not glue registry.

TIA

Any documentation referring to spring cloud stream bindings with AWS Glue registry is helpful

Comment: Have you tried this and run into issues? Can you provide any specific details?